# How to elegantly create matrix with row and column indices as first row / column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have difficulties with creating matrix for specific amount of rows and columns, a matrix that contains indices as first line or column respectively.

```
# At first I create list of lists with 0 at every position

string1 = "dog"
string2 = "hippo"

Dist = [[0 for column in  range(len(string1)+1)] for row in range(len(string2)+1)]
```

I would like to simplify this step if possible:

```
Dist[0] = [x for x in range(len(string1)+1)]

for x in range(len(string2)+1):
        Dist[x][0] = x
```

Here is how the desired and current result looks like (it's a list of lists):

```
print(Dist)
    [[0, 1, 2, 3], 
    [1, 0, 0, 0], 
    [2, 0, 0, 0], 
    [3, 0, 0, 0], 
    [4, 0, 0, 0], 
    [5, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I plan to use this matrix in distance calculation problem, but that is a separate part that I don't need to solve.

My main question is, if I am doing it right (I think not) and how to do it better. Any, even general advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want three separate (aligned) arrays, of shape `(1, 5)`, `(3, 1)`, and `(3, 5)`? Why stack them together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've tagged `numpy`, here is an option with `numpy`:

```
n_cols, n_rows = len(string1)+1, len(string2)+1
Dist = np.zeros((n_rows, n_cols), dtype=np.int32)

Dist[0,:] = np.arange(n_cols)
Dist[:,0] = np.arange(n_rows)
Dist
#array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
#       [1, 0, 0, 0],
#       [2, 0, 0, 0],
#       [3, 0, 0, 0],
#       [4, 0, 0, 0],
#       [5, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I accept this answer because it is higher than MSeiferts, although you both answered at the same minute.

Answer (score 4):

What about just assigning `np.arange`s to a `np.zero` array:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> x = 6
>>> y = 4
>>> arr = np.zeros((x, y), dtype=int)
>>> arr[0, :] = np.arange(y)
>>> arr[:, 0] = np.arange(x)
>>> arr
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Since we are aiming for *elegancy*, here's one compact version with [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) that sets up the range arrays for us and then we can assign both of those first row and column in one step -

```
L1,L2 = len(string1)+1, len(string2)+1
Dist1 = np.zeros((L2,L1),dtype=int)
Dist1[:,[0]], Dist1[0] = np.ogrid[:L2,:L1]
```

Sample output -

```
In [76]: Dist1
Out[76]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 0, 0, 0]])
```